# TYPO3 / Extbase - Switch into another fe_user - and finally back to origin user

Tags: session, typo3, frontend, extbase

I need an approach for switching from current fe_user into another fe_user (similar to backend "simulate user" does) - and back to origin user. The switching into another fe_user itself is not part of the problem. The question is, where to store the origin user (which user to switch back) information? The workflow looks like:

1. If fe_user X (uid: 123) is allowed to "switch" (e.g. member of a certain fe_usergroup)
2. Switch to user A
3. Switch to user B
4. ...and so on...
5. Now switch back to "origin" user X (uid: 123)

The information about the origin user should not be stored into $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user or subarray, i guess. Because that would make user A itself possible to switch back to X (uid: 123), although this user never "was" this user before. So the "switch back" information must be stored anywhere else. But where?

Comment: why dont you just save the uids in the session? Then if you press the switch button, you get the uid you need to switch to and recreate the login process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer myself. The trick is to store the information in session data of type "ses" (as "user" gets overwritten on each switch).

```
if(!$frontendUserAuthentication->getKey('ses', 'tx_ext_originuser')) {
   $frontendUserAuthentication->setKey('ses', 'tx_ext_originuser', $frontendUserAuthentication->user['uid']);
   $frontendUserAuthentication->storeSessionData();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the session storage for getting the information saved. You can save the information for the main fe user in a user session key, which you can use as information, that this is a double session. By logging out, you are able to get the old user and re login.